# Configuração do hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Estou em um projeto java web, usando hibernate, maven, jsf, SGBD postgreeSQL e o container apache tomcat, e agora estou usando o arquivo de configuração do hibernate (cfgConfig.XML) e gostaria de mudar para a configuração de JPA(persistente.XML), MS n sei como fazer. o projeto esta se comunicando com o banco, tudo certinho, e não queria começar tudo de novo. Procurei exaustivamente a solução MS n encontrei nada.

Comment: Olá, Daniel! Sua pergunta é bem abrangente, fica difícil de te ajudar sem saber os detalhes e sem ter um contexto do seu problema. É importante fazer perguntas mais específicas possíveis, assim fica fácil te ajudar.

Comment: Ok Dherid vou tentar reformular a pergunta com mais detalhes, muito obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score -1):

pelo que entendi, seu projeto já está todo funcionando, mas o ideal seria vc criar um novo projeto mesmo, para construí-lo usando o JPA e etc, não é difícil e vc pode copiar suas classes persistentes e DAOs já criados ai.

Dá uma seguida nesse tutorial aqui: https://www.devmedia.com.br/jpa-e-hibernate-acessando-dados-em-aplicacoes-java/32711

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/169369)

Comment: É porque o processo poder um pouco grande para eu explicar aqui, por isso coloquei o link. Mas qualquer pesquisada no google que ele fizer ele acha tutoriais para fazer esse projeto com JPA

Comment: Obrigado @matheus.paulo93, já me aconselharam fazer isso, mas achei que teria uma forma que não precise começar outro projeto, só deixar de usar o hibernate sem JPA, para adicionar as configuração do JPA no projeto. Mas irei seguir o seu conselho, obrigado.